# Doctrine ORM nativeQuery: How to rename table

Tags: doctrine-orm, doctrine-native-query

I'm trying to rename a table with nativeQuery like this:

```
$rsm = new ResultSetMapping();
$query = $em->createNativeQuery('RENAME TABLE `'.$oldname.'` TO `'.$newname.'`', $rsm);
$result = $query->getResult();
```

Strangely the table gets renamed, but the last line throws an error:

```
Undefined offset: 1
.\vendor\doctrine\dbal\src\Driver\PDO\Exception.php:20
.\vendor\doctrine\dbal\src\Driver\PDO\Result.php:107
.\vendor\doctrine\dbal\src\Driver\PDO\Result.php:38
.\vendor\doctrine\dbal\src\Result.php:59
```

What am I missing?

Comment: *What am I missing?* actual error message I would say.

Comment: Blind guess is that you try to handle structure query just like data query which is wrong I would say.

Comment: Sure - sorry :(

Comment: You try to execute DDL quary like it would be a DML select.

Comment: @Antoniossss: Thanks for the hint. I  tried $query->execute() with same result. Is there a method to  execute the query in "structure" mode?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You try to execute DDL query like it would be a DML SELECT. There will be no result set as an outcome of such operation

assuming that `$em` is `EntityManager` do this

```
$em->getConnection()->executeQuery($yourQuery);
```

no `ResultSetMapping` nor other stuff anywhere.

Please be advised that this is not something I have tested myself nor I am active user of the Doctrine. I am convinced as for the cause, not if the snippet is a valid (googled it out)